# Why is my flash animation getting cropped?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

You can view the swf file here :-
http://shrineweb.in/other-files/other/seniorschool.swf

On the above link, the swf is not getting trimmed and plays fine. But when you download it and view in the flash player, it gets trimmed a little from all sides. You will notice that by seeing the half cut 'skip' button at top-right.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your SWF file is published with stage dimensions of 800x650, make sure that your content doesn't exceed those bounds. If it does, change your stage size in your document properties.